# Wine not working : [ERROR]

Tags: wine, 8.04

I just installed wine onto Hardy and I have wine tricks and all that but when i try opening a .exe files by double clicking it or using terminal it just doesn't open.

I have installed Razer Synapse, but when I go in `.wine/drive_c/Program_Files/Razer/Synapse/RzSynapse.exe`, and I run the file, it does nothing.

I tried to open it in the terminal and it shoes me this :

```
felix@predator:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Razer/Synapse$ wine RzSynapse.exe
Missing method .ctor in assembly C:\Program Files\Razer\Synapse\RzSynapse.exe, type System.Windows.ThemeInfoAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: C:\Program Files\Razer\Synapse\RzSynapse.exe mtoken: 0x0a00000e

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
felix@predator:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Razer/Synapse$`
```

Anyone have any idea? I'm not very experienced with Wine :)

Thanks!

Comment: Your Ubuntu version is way out of date! you might be experiencing a bug. you must upgrade it to any of the recent versions through [the ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install .net 4.0 framework using winetricks. You can do the install much easier in [Playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/). Which is third party wine wrapper and contains the necessary install scripts.